# Run a User Custom Action with Powershell

Tags: powershell, custom-actions

Can you run a UserCustomAction with Powershell? I am planing to automate a process and this is the easiest way.

Comment: sharepoint online or on prem?

Comment: sharepoint on-prem

Comment: do you want to deploy/add a custom action using PS ? sorry i didnt understand :(

Comment: I wan to run it, as if I am calling a function

Answer (score 2):

See your question isn't quite clear but userCustomactions are possible using the web object that powershell provides.

You can deploy it on a list or library.

```
 $web = get-spweb "http://exampleURL.com"
 $appType = $web.lists[$listTitle]
 $exampleAction = $appType.UserCustomActions.Add();

 $exampleAction.Url = "ExampleURL"
 $exampleAction.Location = "Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls"

 $exampleAction.Title = "Give it a title"
 $exampleAction.Description  = "Give it a description"
 $exampleAction.Update()
```

Comment: Why is this upvoted? OP asked for a way to RUN it, not a way to add it to a list.